# Regex date format for dash or forward slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex which finds a string pattern of any of the following formats

```
28.05.2018 SB RS CS  
28-05-2018 SB RS CS  
28/05/2018 SB RS CS
```

The regular expressions matches the first example with the full stops in the date, but does not match the second and third example with the dashes and forward slashes in the date.

Can any one please advise how to correct the regular expression so that it matches a dash or a forward slash?

Any assistance will be most appreciated.

The script is part of an Adobe javascript.

```
var re = new RegExp(
"\\d{1,2}[\\-\\/\\.]\\d{1,2}[\\-\\/\\.]\\d{2,4}\\s([A-Z]{2,5})\\s([A-Z]{2,5})\\s([A-Z]{2,5})"
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\d{1,2}[/.-]\d{1,2}[/.-]\d{2,4}\s([A-Z]{2,5})\s([A-Z]{2,5})\s([A-Z]{2,5})
```

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ehgu1T/1/)

Notes:

You were really close, in a character class you do not need to escape the dash (if you put it at the end of the class definition) and the dot.

```js
console.log("test 28.05.2018 SB RS CS test 28-05-2018 SB RS CS abc 28/05/2018 SB RS CS 123".match(/\d{1,2}[/.-]\d{1,2}[/.-]\d{2,4}\s([A-Z]{2,5})\s([A-Z]{2,5})\s([A-Z]{2,5})/g));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Allan.  Your answer is correct, however when I run the script in Adobe on a pdf file it still only matches the date with the full stop. Not sure why the regex not working, as it is working on the regex tester, any ideas?

Comment: Hi Allan,  when I run the script on a pdf file it still only matches the date with the full stop, not the date with the dash or forward slash, any ideas as to why this would not work?

Comment: @JoJo: That's really strange it should work... Are you sure there are not hidden characters? Also if you replace the regex in a `Regexp` variable you need to add `\` before each `\`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  String formateDateOfBirth(String? dob) {
    return '$dob'.replaceAllMapped(
        RegExp(r'(\d{2})(\d{2})'), (Match m) => '${m[1]}/${m[2]}');
  }
```

This will give with "mm/dd" formatting for month and day. eg: 01/25
You can customize also `MM/dd/yyyy` or any `yyyy-MM-dd` as per requirement.